# Getting 404 Error when URL contains double slash after Spring Boot 2.5 to 2.6 migration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-actuator

The following URL used to return 200 with Spring Boot 2.5

http://localhost:8080//actuator/health

After upgrading to 2.6 it no longer works and returns 404 Not Found

I spotted the error because some of the project's integration tests were failing (requests returned 404). Then I noticed the double slash, and after removing it, the issue was fixed.

I just want to understand which feature causes this new behavior?

I went through the 2.6 [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes) several times, but nothing rings a bell.

Comment: If you're using Spring MVC, this may be due to the change to the default path matching strategy: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#pathpattern-based-path-matching-strategy-for-spring-mvc.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I tried setting it back to  spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy to ant-path-matcher but the double slash variant still doesn't work..

Comment: As described in the last paragraph of that section in the release notes, that is to be expected: "Note that the path matching strategy for actuator endpoints is not configurable via a configuration property."

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. The path matching strategy was changed and cannot be configured for the actuator endpoints, which is exactly my case.

Answer (score 4):

The issue was that the path matching strategy has changed. The actuator path pattern CANNOT be overwritten by

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher
```

The solution was to manually fix the URLs containing double slashes.

Comment: I think now it become with underscore
`spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher`

Answer (score 3):

1. Are you able to access actuator endpoint with single slash? like http://localhost:8080/actuator/health
2. If yes, then did you configure the spring security for your application? There is a configuration you can define where your application will allow consecutive slashes in url.

   ```
   @Bean
   HttpFirewall httpFirewall() {
       StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
       firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedDoubleSlash(true);
       return firewall;
   }
   ```

Comment: 1. Yes 2. I don't have spring security in the project. As I mentioned, the 2.5 version was working with // in the URL. I am just trying to find out an explanation what caused the change in the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

here maybe the reason :
PathPattern Based Path Matching Strategy for Spring MVC

The default strategy for matching request paths against registered Spring MVC handler mappings has changed from AntPathMatcher to PathPatternParser.

fix:

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher
```

Comment: in webFlux is not worked

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Spring boot 3:

1. Create the `RequestRejectedException` handler:

```
@Component
public class CustomRequestRejectedHandler implements RequestRejectedHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, RequestRejectedException ex) throws IOException {
        req.setAttribute("custom-error-id", ex.getMessage());
        res.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
    }
}
```

It will intercept `RequestRejectedException`, where you can customize http status and add some additional info for exception identification, which will be used in the next steps.

2. Spring will redirect that handled error to `/error` endpoint, which you also need to implement. Create something like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/error")
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        var httpStatus = resolveHttpStatus(request);
        var errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(extractErrorMessage(request, httpStatus));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, httpStatus);
    }

    protected HttpStatus resolveHttpStatus(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Integer statusCode = (Integer) request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);
        if (statusCode == null) {
            return HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        }

        return Arrays.stream(HttpStatus.values())
                .filter(status -> status.value() == statusCode)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    private String extractErrorMessage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpStatus httpStatus) {
        var errorMessage = (String) request.getAttribute("custom-error-id");
        if (!Strings.isBlank(errorMessage)) {
            return errorMessage;
        } else {
            return httpStatus.getReasonPhrase();
        }
    }
}
```

3. Finally add `/error` endpoint to the spring WebSecurity configutration exclusion list:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
...
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain web(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            ...
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth-> auth
                .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll();
        ...
        return http.build();
    }
```

4. For integration tests: implement them using `WebTestClient`.